# Using tf.train.Saver() on convolutional layers in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm attempting to use `tf.train.Saver()` to apply transfer learning between two convolutional neural network graphs in tensorflow and I'd like to validate that my methods are working as expected.  Is there a way to inspect the trainable features in a `tf.layers.conv2d()` layer?

### My methods

#### 1. initialize layer

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=X_reshaped, filters=conv1_fmaps, kernel_size=conv1_ksize,
                             strides=conv1_stride, padding=conv1_pad, 
                             activation=tf.nn.relu, 
                             kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), 
                             bias_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), trainable=True, 
                             name="conv1")
```

#### 2. {Train the network}

#### 3. Save current graph

`tf.train.Saver().save(sess, "./my_model_final.ckpt")`

#### 4. Build new graph that includes the same layer, load specified weights with `Saver()`

```
reuse_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES,
                               scope="conv[1]") 
reuse_vars_dict = dict([(var.op.name, var) for var in reuse_vars])
restore_saver = tf.train.Saver(reuse_vars_dict)
```

...

`restore_saver.restore(sess, "./my_model_final.ckpt")`

#### 5. {Train and evaluate the new graph}

### My Question:

1) My code works 'as expected' and without error, but I'm not 100% confident it's  working like I think it is.  Is there a way to print the trainable features from a layer to ensure that I'm loading and saving weights correctly?  Is there a "better" way to save/load parameters with the `tf.layers` API? I noticed a  [request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12746) on GitHub related to this. Ideally, I'd like to check these values on the first graph a) after initialization b) after training and on the new graph i) after loading the weights ii) after training/evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is there a way to print the trainable features from a layer to ensure that I'm loading and saving weights correctly?

Yes, you first need to get a handle on the layer's variables. There are several ways to do that, but arguably the simplest is using the `get_collection()` function:

```
conv1_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES,
                               scope="conv1")
```

Note that the scope here is treated as a regular expression, so you can write things like `conv[123]` if you want all variables from scopes `conv1`, `conv2` and `conv3`.

If you just want trainable variables, you can replace `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` with `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`.

If you just want to check a single variable, such as the layer's kernel, then you can use `get_tensor_by_name()` like this:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
kernel_var = graph.get_tensor_by_name("conv1/kernel:0")
```

Yet another option is to just iterate on all variables and filter based on their names:

```
conv1_vars = [var for var in tf.global_variables()
              if var.op.name.startswith("conv1/")]
```

Once you have a handle on these variables, you can just evaluate them at different points, e.g. just after initialization, just after restoring the graph, just after training, and so on, and compare the values. For example, this is how you would get the values just after initialization:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    conv1_var_values_after_init = sess.run(conv1_vars)
```

Then once you have captured the variable values at the various points that you are interested in, you can check whether or not they are equal (or close enough, taking into account tiny floating point imprecisions) like so:

```
same = np.allclose(conv1_var_values_after_training,
                   conv1_var_values_after_restore)
```

- Is there a "better" way to save/load parameters with the tf.layers API?

Not that I'm aware of. The feature request you point to is not really about saving/loading the parameters to disk, but rather to be able to easily get a handle on a layer's variables, and to easily create an assignment node to set their values.

For example, it will be possible (in TF 1.4) to get a handle on a layer's kernel and get its value very simply, like this:

```
conv1_kernel_value = conv1.kernel.eval()
```

Of course, you can use this to get/set a variable's value and load/save it to disk, like this:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(...)
new_kernel = tf.placeholder(...)
assign_kernel = conv1.kernel.assign(new_kernel)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    loaded_kernel = my_function_to_load_kernel_value_from_disk(...)
    assign_kernel.run(feed_dict={new_kernel: loaded_kernel})
    ...
```

It's not pretty. It might be useful if you want to load/save to a database (instead of a flat file), but in general I would recommend using a `Saver`.

I hope this helps.